# Can i preview terminal bash output in kivy 2d gui

Tags: python, kivy

I try lot of combination.
Window just freez to the moment of job finish.
No way to get ouput in Button.text = ....

Any suggestion

```
        process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        #with process.stdout:
        #    self.log_subprocess_output(process.stdout)
        myLogs = []
        for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b'\n'): # b'\n'-separated lines
            myLogs.append( str(line) )
            print(str(line))
        # print('got line from subprocess: %r', line)
        # print('Take one line:', myLogs[30])
        #while True:
        #    line = process.stdout.readline()
        #    if line != '':
        #        test_str = str(subprocess.check_output(["echo", line]))
        #        # self.LOGS.text =+ test_str
        #        print(subprocess.check_output(["echo", line]))
        #    else:
        #        break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running that code in the main thread, then your app will be unresponsive until the subprocess finishes. To fix that, just run that code in another thread.